# Cannot align legend's text in plots using tikzpicture package

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, legend

I'm trying to align the text (text + $math$) within the legend in my pgfplot. Despite I put the "legend cell align=left", the text still is centred. Any guess?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots} 
  \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!t]
      \subfloat[caption subfig 1]{
         \resizebox{.45 \linewidth}{!}{%
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel={labelX}, ylabel={labelY}, ymin=16, xmin=53, ymax=35.2, xmax=58, legend cell align=left, legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}]
             \addplot[mark=x,red,only marks] table[x index=6,y index=7]{./figures1.txt};
             \addlegendentry{\large{text + math $h_{1}$}}
             \addplot[mark=o,blue,only marks] table[x index=6,y index=7]{./figures2.txt};
             \addlegendentry{\large{more text + math $h_{1}$}}
           \end{axis}
         \end{tikzpicture}
      }
   }
\qquad
\subfloat[caption subfig 2]{
   \resizebox{.45 \linewidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[xlabel={labelX}, ylabel={labelY}, ymin=16, xmin=53, ymax=35.2, xmax=58, legend cell align=left, legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}]
       \addplot[mark=x,red,only marks] table[x index=6,y index=7]{./figures3.txt};
       \addlegendentry{\large{text + math $h_{1}$}}
       \addplot[mark=o,blue,only marks] table[x index=6,y index=7]{./figures4.txt};
       \addlegendentry{\large{more text + math $h_{1}$}}
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
\caption{caption fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Compiling your example (please test it before posting) gives me left aligned labels.

Comment: Please test your code and make sure it compiles and no packages are missing.